# Custom arrow tip example from PGF manual

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code pasted from the PGF manual pag. 1025 does not compile on my end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfdeclarearrow{
name = foo,
parameters = { \the\pgfarrowlength },
setup code = {
% The different end values:
\pgfarrowssettipend{.25\pgfarrowlength}
\pgfarrowssetlineend{-.25\pgfarrowlength}
\pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
\pgfarrowssetbackend{-.75\pgfarrowlength}
% The hull
\pgfarrowshullpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}
\pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}
\pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
% Saves: Only the length:
\pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
},
drawing code = {
\pgfpathmoveto{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}
\pgfpathlineto{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}
\pgfpathlineto{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}
\pgfpathlineto{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepathqfill
},
defaults = { length = 4cm }
}


\begin{document}

\tikz \draw [-foo] (0,0) -- (8,0);

\end{document}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I can confirm that the MWE above does not compile with an error about a missing number for `\advance`.

Comment: It seems to work if you `\pgfpathmoveto{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}` by `\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}` and do the same for the lines containing `pgfpathlineto`. According to the doc, `\pgfpathmoveto` and `\pgfpathmoveto` now take a PGF-Coordinate and not x and y values. It seems that the example was not updated to reflect the (new ? - not sure) syntax of this command. You could notify the author so he can fix this small issue in the next release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drawing code is actually this:

```
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepathqfill
```

If you put that instead of the one you have, it works.

I checked the manual source. The used code is different from what you see in the PDF. Don't know why.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I find the manual source code?

Comment: With TeX Live: `texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/text-en/pgfmanual-en-base-arrows.tex`

Comment: It's a typo. What you have should have been stated instead.